# PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR on fetching images from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, firewall

Some of my site users started getting errors (for one user I saw `PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR` error) when trying to view images served from S3.
This started a couple days ago, while my S3 bucket is in use for about 4 years now without any change in configuration in the past year or more.

I'm suspecting that one or more ISPs here have changed their firewall settings, since one of the users affected has tried viewing the images through mobile phone, and it failed while he was on his home WIFI, and succeeded while using cellular network.

My S3 properties:

- US-east-1
- Server-side encryption with Amazon S3 managed keys (SSE-S3)

My S3 permissions:

- Has public access
- Using ACL and enabling everyone to read

CORS configuration as follows:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2",
            "ETag"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

How can I fix this?